# KOMA Report: how to set the distance between page border and page number on top of page

Tags: header-footer, positioning, koma-script, page-numbering, report

Using KOMA Report, I want have the page number in the top center, 1.25 cm away from the top page border, and maintain a top margin of 2.5 cm.

I am using

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

with

```
\chead*{\pagemark}
```

but I don't know how to set the page number positioning, without affecting the rest of the layout. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe  `headsep=\dimexpr1.25cm-1em\relax` as geometry option. Or you could change the vertical position of the header layer.

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show an short compilable TeX code resulting in your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Without `geometry` you could use:

```
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \setlength{\topmargin}{\dimexpr 1.25cm-1in\relax}%
  \setlength{\headsep}{\dimexpr 1.25cm-\headheight\relax}%
}
\recalctypearea
```

Here `typearea` command `\AfterCalculatingTypearea` is used to change the top margin and the distance between the head and the text area after each change of the typing area. `\recalctypearea` is needed, to execute the changes at least once.

With `geometry` you can do something similar:

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,headsep=\dimexpr 1.25cm-\headheight\relax]{geometry}
```

Here as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[headlines=1]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,headsep=\dimexpr 1.25cm-\headheight\relax]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\pagemark}

% Only some demonstration code to add a page grid and to frame the page areas:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%
  \thinlines\color{gray}%
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){211}{\line(0,1){297}}%
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){298}{\line(1,0){210}}%
  \thicklines\color{red}%
  \multiput(0,0)(10,0){21}{\line(0,1){297}}%
  \multiput(0,7)(0,10){29}{\line(1,0){210}}%
}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: page number 1.25cm from top edge]